# How to know what type of object is pointing a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I have a base class named Cell (other class has a pointer to an object of this class), and 3 derivated classes CellA, CellB and CellC. When a cell is dead, the pointer points to Cell, in other case is alive (A,B or C). How to know what is pointing that pointer in this moment to act??

Comment: Have a virtual `IsAlive` method.

Comment: Who is "the pointer" in your narrative?

Answer (score 1):

In case your classes are polymorphic You can use **[dynamic_cast](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc05keyword_dynamic_cast.htm)**.
`dynamic_cast` allows you to safely downcast pointers.
In your case, You can use `dynamic_cast` to check if the Base class pointer is pointing to a derived instance, `dynamic_cast` can report you that information.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a little bit different logic, take a look on states design pattern I think it could help you. Normally the casting is a bad thing and should be avoided. If you need a casting then you probably have a design issue....

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks but that desing is a mini-hell created by my teachers xDDD

Answer (score 0):

use `dynamic_case` or `typeid()` to know the object at runtime...